# Use Lodash to find objects in an array matches an id (complex, drilldown)

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a set of id's.

```
let ids = ["5ae03c56dc0e82410d2746d7", "5ae05bf146e0fbeeb1869d7b", "5ae03c56dc0e82fd2f2746d6", "5ae04788c9e77cb0a03b3228", "5adefec246e0fb1c23f5ba6b", "5ae8498edc0e82c7cbad5026", "5ae84b4fc9e77c5db6fbf3f8"]
```

I also have a set of data that looks like the following.

```
{  
    "interactions":[  
        {  
            "author":{  
                "id":"10158567383880542",
                "name":"Stephen Wilson"
            },
            "meta":{  
                "tags":[  
                    {  
                        "id":"5ae04788c9e77cb0a03b3228"
                    },
                    {  
                        "id":"5ae04788c9e77cb0a03b365"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Inside the interactions array there are multiple objects. There is a property called "meta", inside the meta there is a property of type array called "tags".

I want to match the ids array to find and return any interactions where meta.tags.id is equal to any of the ids.

```
 let matches = _(interactions)
            .keyBy('meta.tags.id')
            .at(ids)
            .value();
```

The problem with the attempt here is that meta.tags is an array.

Comment: I've seen lodash has quite a lot of functions that can help you do that

Comment: What should be the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Code:

```js
const ids = ["5ae05bf146e0fbeeb1869d7b", "5ae03c56dc0e82fd2f2746d6"]
const data = {"interactions":[{"author":{"id":"10158567383880542","name":"Stephen Wilson"},"meta":{"tags":[{"id":"5ae04788c9e77cb0a03b3228"},{"id":"5ae04788c9e77cb0a03b365"}]}},{"author":{"id":"10158567383880543","name":"Phil Murray"},"meta":{"tags":[{"id":"5ae05bf146e0fbeeb1869d7b"},{"id":"5ae04788c9e77cb0a03b369"}]}},{"author":{"id":"10158567383880543","name":"Steve Jobs"},"meta":{"tags":[{"id":"5ae84b4fc9e77c5db6fbf3f8"},{"id":"5ae04788c9e77cb0a44469"}]}},{"author":{"id":"10158567383880543","name":"John Connor"},"meta":{"tags":[{"id":"5ae84b4fc9e778c5db6fbf3f8"},{"id":"5ae04788c94577cb0a44469"}]}}]};

const result = data.interactions.filter(i => i.meta.tags.some(t => ids.includes(t.id)));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Nice one. - at least shorter than mine :)

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for a separate library. You can use straight javascript filtering and mapping here:

```js
const ids = ["5ae03c56dc0e82410d2746d7", "5ae05bf146e0fbeeb1869d7b", "5ae03c56dc0e82fd2f2746d6", "5ae04788c9e77cb0a03b3228", "5adefec246e0fb1c23f5ba6b", "5ae8498edc0e82c7cbad5026", "5ae84b4fc9e77c5db6fbf3f8"]
const inters = {
  "interactions": [{
      "author": {
        "id": "10158567383880542",
        "name": "Stephen Wilson"
      },
      "meta": {
        "tags": [{
          "id": "5ae04788c9e77cb0a03b3228"
        }, {
          "id": "5ae04788c9e77cb0a03b365"
        }]
      }
    },
    {
      "author": {
        "id": "10158567383880543",
        "name": "Phil Murray"
      },
      "meta": {
        "tags": [{
          "id": "5ae05bf146e0fb345eeb1869d7b"
        }, {
          "id": "5ae04788c9e3477cb0a03b369"
        }]
      }
    },
    {
      "author": {
        "id": "10158567383880543",
        "name": "Steve Jobs"
      },
      "meta": {
        "tags": [{
          "id": "5ae8498edc0e82c7cbad5026"
        }, {
          "id": "5ae84b4fc9e77c5db6fbf3f8"
        }]
      }
    },
    {
      "author": {
        "id": "10158567383880543",
        "name": "John Connor"
      },
      "meta": {
        "tags": [{
          "id": "5ae8498edc0e82c7cbad5026"
        }, {
          "id": "5ae84b4fc9e77c5db6fbf3f8"
        }]
      }
    }
  ]
};

const matching = ids
  .map(
    id => inters.interactions.filter(interaction => interaction.meta.tags.some(tag => tag.id === id))
  )
  .filter(item => item.length > 0)
  .reduce((flattened, item) => {
    return flattened.concat(item);
  }, []);
console.log(matching);
```

Comment: because we want to get **all** interactions where the `meta.tags` contain an `id`, not just whether the first has one. Of course you could do it with some flavor of `for`-loop, but I prefere functional style.

Comment: @Kay wrote: "Inside the interactions array there are multiple objects." Your code is correct for the data, but not for the spec.

Comment: This returns the first occurrence as appose to all occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

Filter is enough. No need for a library

```js
const ids = ["5ae03c56dc0e82410d2746d7", "5ae05bf146e0fbeeb1869d7b", "5ae03c56dc0e82fd2f2746d6", "5ae04788c9e77cb0a03b3228", "5adefec246e0fb1c23f5ba6b", "5ae8498edc0e82c7cbad5026", "5ae84b4fc9e77c5db6fbf3f8"]

const inter = { "interactions":[ 
  { "author":{ "id":"10158567383880542", "name":"Stephen Wilson 1" }, "meta":{ "tags":[ { "id":"5ae04788c9e77cb0a03b3228" }, { "id":"5ae04788c9e77cb0a03b365" } ] } }, 
  { "author":{ "id":"10158567383880542", "name":"Stephen Wilson 2" }, "meta":{ "tags":[ { "id":"xxx" }, { "id":"yyy" } ] } }, 
  { "author":{ "id":"10158567383880542", "name":"Stephen Wilson 3" }, "meta":{ "tags":[ { "id":"5ae03c56dc0e82fd2f2746d6" }, { "id":"5ae84b4fc9e77c5db6fbf3f8" } 

] } } ] } 


let found = [];
inter.interactions.forEach(function(act,index) {
  let actFound = act.meta.tags.filter(function(item) { return ids.indexOf(item.id) !=-1 });
  if (actFound.length>0) found = found.concat(inter.interactions[index]); // or use ...spread
})  
console.log(found)
```

Comment: @Kay wrote: "I want to match the ids array to find and return any interactions where meta.tags.id is equal to any of the ids." Your code regards only the first `interaction`, ignoring the case that there might be multiple objects in the `interactions` array.

Comment: Updated to handle more than one interaction

Comment: This does not return the original interaction